# Invalid Session id in salesforce RestAPI

Tags: rest-api

am trying get all sobjects in another organization ,,i got session id when am trying to to invoke this am getting error like this

```
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]
```

here is my code

```
 public void myConnection (){

   HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            request.setEndpoint('https://www.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/27.0');
            request.setMethod('POST');
            request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
            request.setHeader('SOAPAction', '""');
            request.setBody('<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Header/><Body><login xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"><username>' +uname + '</username><password>' + password+'</password></login></Body></Envelope>');

             Dom.XmlNode resultElmt = (new Http()).send(request).getBodyDocument().getRootElement()
              .getChildElement('Body', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')
              .getChildElement('loginResponse', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com')
              .getChildElement('result', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com');

            final String SERVER_URL = resultElmt.getChildElement('serverUrl', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com') .getText().split('/services')[0];
            final String SESSION_ID = resultElmt.getChildElement('sessionId', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com') .getText();
            // SESSION_ID1=SESSION_ID;




            HttpRequest request1 = new HttpRequest();
              request1.setEndpoint('https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/query/?q=SELECT+name+from+Account');

              request1.setMethod('GET');
              // request1.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
               //request1.setHeader('SOAPAction', '""');
             //  request1.setHeader('Content-Length',String.valueOf(JSONString .length()));
              // request1.setBody(account);
               request1.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth '+SESSION_ID);
                 String body = (new Http()).send(request1).getBody();
                 system.debug('**************************'+body);
                response=body ;
getobjects();


}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What do you mean by "another organization"? Another Salesforce org? How do you determine SERVER_URL and SESSION_ID?

Comment: yea its another salesforce org ..when we are doing successful handshake with another salesforce org ,it return url and sessionid .that is what i mentioned it .

Comment: So it would be helpful to see the code to use to login and determine these values so that we can see your program flow.

Comment: @FrankZ Please go through it ..i made a few changes to it

Comment: I am wondering why you login through the SOAP API and then try to use the REST API. Have you tried the methods described in http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/intro_understanding_authentication.htm

Answer (score 6):

The SessionID is only valid on the returned ServerURL.

On your line:

```
request1.setEndpoint('https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/query/?q=SELECT+name+from+Account');
```

you need to replace `https://ap1.salesforce.com/` with the value returned in ServerURL. Note that if you were doing an [OAuth Authentication Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm) you would be looking for the `instance_url`, which contains the same data as the ServerUrl from the SOAP based login.

---

Also, I don't think this is correct if you want to use the SessionID to authenticate the request.

```
request1.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth '+SESSION_ID);
```

Instead it should be:

```
request1.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+SESSION_ID);
```

Comment: For the moment, both *Bearer* and *OAuth* are accepted in the *Authorization* header. The docs do say *Bearer*, but some of the older docs had *OAuth* instead. In fact, I just tested the latter in my browser's console to confirm it still works. It does.

Comment: @sfdcfox Good to know. I was just going off what I know worked for me when reusing a Session ID I got from the SOAP API with the Analytics REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Bah. I can't comment on @Daniel Ballinger's answer, so I'm adding this here. I think you mean instead of "Server URL", the "instance_url" value returned when the token was generated. At least when using the username-password flow as doc'd [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm).

Comment: In the question the request was being sent the the SOAP based login call, so the response would have contained the ServerURL. But yes, for the REST based flows it would be `instance_url`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, i concatenated the Password and security token created from my user and passed.

It is working fine now