# Invalid session id in rest api

Tags: rest-api

I am getting Invalid session id when I am executing the below code. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

```
public class ResttestController {

    public String response{get;set;}
    public String dccName{get;set;}

    public PageReference Donate() {
        //find access token using Auth 2.0 
        String Access_Token='##############################################.$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$';
        Httprequest req=new httprequest();
        String domainName='ap2.salesforce.com';
        String endPointURL='https://'+domainName+'/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/Donations';
        req.setendpoint(endPointURL);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml; charset=utf-8');
        req.setBody('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><request><name>'+dccName+ </request>');
        req.setmethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Authorization','Authorization: Bearer '+Access_Token);
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        response=res.getbody();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: chk if it helps , http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21621/invalid-session-id-in-salesforce-restapi

Answer (score 1):

Change following line

```
req.setHeader('Authorization','Authorization: Bearer '+Access_Token);
```

to

```
req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+Access_Token);
```

I assume that `Access_Token` is correct.

Comment: Hi.. Access_Token is the Consumer Key in connected apps.. Right???? i hv used the same.. I am still getting the same error

Comment: @hellraizer You have to request the access token first using ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret.

Answer (score 1):

To get the Access Token you need to run the Login API

[How to Get Access Token](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/get-access-token.htm)

Once you get the access token you can use any of the salesforce REST API.
You are passing the header wrong it should be like

`req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + Access_Token);`

then it should run properly.